# Is prevention of action a requirement for someone to be 'deterred'?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, differences

After looking at Merriam-Webster, Oxford, and dictionary.com, I'm left unsure about how closely "prevent" and "deter" are related.

I had always known the words to mean the same thing, just operating on different objects:  By "deterring" the person, you "prevent" their action.

But is prevention of the action actually necessary?  If the person still performs the action, were they still deterred?  I had always thought not.

Is it possible for someone to be deterred but their action not be prevented?

EDIT:

Adding example for clarification:

Bob wants to date my sister. I don't want him to, so I tell him that if he does, I will punch him. He gets scared, but not enough to completely dissuade him, so he dates my sister anyway.

No action was prevented. So, did I "deter" him or not?

I had always thought not.  After all, if he went through with it, that means he wasn't deterred, right?

I envision this as a black and white cutoff.  If the action was prevented (as a result of my threat), the actor was deterred. Otherwise, they were not. Is that correct?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you're asking whether there can be degrees of deterrence, or if it's a binary either-deterred-or-not, no-in-between kind of thing. In other words, can one be a little bit deterred? If that's what you're wondering, you may want to clarify in the question.

Comment: I always think of "deterred" as being something in between "discouraged" and "prevented." So I do think someone could be deterred without being prevented, but saying that they were deterred means that there was some extra hindrance placed in their way.

Comment: Thanks.  I edited to include an example that relates to my question.

Whoops, @spoko:  so your answer to this would be that prevention is not a requirement, and that I did deter Bob?

Comment: @SomeGuy: I had thought so, but then I looked at the example you added. And my description of Bob in that scenario would be "undeterred." So I'm rethinking my stance.

Comment: [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/deter) has << **deter** verb 1 Discourage (someone) from doing something by instilling doubt or fear of the consequences. >>  [and](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/discourage) << **discourage** ... verb ... 1.1 Prevent or try to prevent (something) by showing disapproval or creating difficulties.>> // And [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/deter) has << **deter** verb: ...

Comment: to prevent someone from doing something or to make someone less enthusiastic about doing something by making it difficult for that person to do it or by threatening bad results if they do it >> [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deter)  has << **deter**: to turn aside, discourage, or prevent from acting >>.  What is unclear about this? General reference. // Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You may find my answer below interesting. I believe the meaning changes depending on whether you know the outcome. If I say "He was deterred from going" that clearly seems to say that he didn't go, not just that he had some bad vibes about it, but still went.

Comment: @WS2 The dictionaries clearly give both the 'put obstacles in the way of someone' and 'prevent a course of action by putting obstacles in the way of someone' senses. If the dissuasion is a known fact: (a) if this failed to stop the action being taken, obviously the 'prevent' sense cannot apply. (b) if the action has not been taken at this point in time, who knows whether this state will continue?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Where you refer to "the dictionaries clearly give...", are you able to tell us which dictionaries you are quoting, and what they say. I think the OP might find this helpful.

Comment: @WS2 You want me to repeat my earlier comments?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good question and the OED does not provide clarity.

The word comes from the Latin *deterrere* - to frighten. But that doesn't get us far.

OED sense 1a says:

> trans. To discourage and turn aside or restrain by fear; to frighten
>   from anything; to restrain or keep back from acting or proceeding by
>   any consideration of danger or trouble.
>
> 1854   H. H. Milman Hist. Lat. Christianity I. iii. vii. 461
>   Maurice..had been deterred by the alarming prophecy of a monk. 1877
>   J. D. Chambers Divine Worship Eng. 308   To deter instead of to invite
>   communicants.

In practice I suspect "deter" does get used both ways.

People definitely say things like "he was undeterred" - meaning, presumably, he was not prevented.

But I feel sure that it is also used, in the following sense too  "health warnings on cigarette packets are a deterrence, but some still smoke".

**Unlike "prevent", "deter" is uncertain. If I say "I will prevent it from happening" you know the eventual outcome. It will not happen. But if you say "I will deter him from coming" - you don't at that moment know if it will work. He may still come. But you still use the word "deter". So in that sense "deter" is only an action designed to prevent. However if I say "He was deterred from going", at that point I know the outcome - so the meaning is that he didn't go. So the meaning is dependent on whether you know the outcome**.

Comment: In your cigarette/group example, I would argue that meaning is the same.  If something is a deterrent, that doesn't necessarily imply that all are deterred.  Contrarily, for something to be a deterrent, at least SOMEONE must be deterred.  Ultimately, if a deterrent does not prevent anything, how can you call it a deterrent? Prevention appears to be a requirement.    ---  Or so this is what I always thought.

Comment: @SomeGuy Interesting comment.

Comment: @SomeGuy  I think I have grasped this. Unlike "prevent", "deter" is uncertain. If I say "I will prevent it from happening" you know the eventual outcome. It will not happen. But if you say "I will deter him from coming" - you don't at that moment know if it will work. He may still come. But you still use the word "deter". So in that sense it is only a hope. However if I say "He was deterred from going", at that point I know the outcome - so the meaning is that he didn't go. So the meaning is dependent on whether you know the outcome.

Comment: This seems like a very reasonable answer, and clarifies things the most for me.  Thank you.  Though I'm going to wait a bit more to see if there are more responses before I accept.  On a side note, I have a very long discussion with Bernadette in the comments for her answer -- and I don't want to dismiss her answer but it seems to be more confusing to me than helpful.  If you have the time and interest, I would appreciate your thoughts on her take, as well.  Though if you don't want to bother with that I completely understand.  Thanks again.

Comment: @SomeGuy I believe that thread deals as much with the meaning of "prevent" as that of "deter". Both of these words are clearly nuanced according to context, and idiom, and often act together. Neither has an absolute meaning. For my part I've not given too much thought to "prevent", though I'm aware that I did refer to it in my answer, as a word which indicated a more certain outcome.  But I think we are in danger of getting confused if we consider the two words in tandem. Let's try and stick with one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent and deter are different, you prevent a person leaving by locking the door and keeping the only key, you deter from leaving them by convinvincing them not to leave for whatever reason. You do not prevent somebody completing and action by convincing them not to because if they are convinced not to, then they had choice and were not prevented.

To be prevented is to be stopped by an outside force and to be deterred is ultimately the person's decision based on the deterrent factors.

When they change their mind and follow through with the action they are no longer deterred.

To answer the question look at the word undeterred, if a person was undeterred, they complete the action without hesitation regardless of what deterrents are in the way. If they were hesitant but continued, they may have been deterred in some way although have overcome that.

At the point the date in the example occurred he was no longer deterred although he had been deterred at the point he was scared of being punched.

Comment: This hinges on prevention requiring physical interaction, though, which I don't think it does.  If I talk someone out of killing themselves, you would say I deterred them  -- but did I also not **prevent** their suicide?

Comment: Ultimately did you prevent his suicide by making him choose not to do it or by removing his means to do it?
If you helped him choose not to do it then you deterred it, not prevented it, you did not stop him, he chose not to do it himself based on what you had said.
To have prevented him you would have had to remove the means to commit suicide- therefore a physical action.

Comment: The robbery, the physical action was prevented yes, although the person was not prevented, only deterred as you say.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted that comment because I didn't see your reply and wanted to read it before posting.  Here was my original comment before deleting:

A more on point example: A man plans to rob a bank. He walks in the door with his weapon ready, but sees an armed guard, gets scared, changes his mind, and leaves. We both agree the man was deterred, but was the robbery not also prevented? Though your point about whether or not someone is deterred changing over time is interesting

Comment: This is what is confusing me: "the person was not prevented" <-  I thought the object of 'prevent' had to be an action (in this case, the robbery). What does it even mean to prevent a person?

Comment: Also, if you agree that the robbery was prevented by the deterrent, doesn't that contradict the first paragraph of your answer where you say prevention requires physical intervention?  I'm sorry if I sound like I'm arguing.  I'm not trying to argue, I'm just very confused by this.

Comment: The physical intervention was that prevented the robbery was the presence the guard.

Comment: But... how is that different from talking someone out of something?  If I talk Bob out of suicide, isn't the physical intervention that prevented his suicide the presence of me?

Comment: The robber was not prevented, only the robbery, the robber could walk down the road to another bank that has no physical barrier (guard) to deter them and make them chose not to do that robbery therefore both are achieved deterring the robber (choice) and preventing the robbery (action).

Comment: But those are two different actions, are they not?  One was deterred and prevented, the other wasn't.  And I'm sorry but I still don't know what "the robber was not prevented" is supposed to mean.  Doesn't the object of 'prevent' have to be an action?  When you say the robber was prevented, do you mean all future robberies they may have committed were prevented?

Comment: We are responding too quickly to each other!!

If you talked him out of suicide then it was not your presence that prevented it only your words that deterred him. Ultimately he chose not to do it, you could say he prevented it himself by not taking that particular physical action. Therefore, it is probably more correct to state that prevention is usually physical but more specifically includes an external force as I said in my original comment but admit I waned on in later comments.

I am off to bed now after nightshift but will check back in later.

Comment: To put the robber scenario a different way, nothing actually prevented the robber from attempting to continue with the robbery did it? He could have still gone in 'undeterred' and taken the risk.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience Bernadette. I'm trying my best to understand but this is all very confusing.  If I'm understanding correctly, you're saying that prevention demands a physical inability of the act to be performed.  Whereas if it is possible for the act to be performed but the actor chooses not to because of possible consequences, that would be determent?  My big hurdle is that the [online] OED and M-W definitions for "prevent" seem to give no indication that force is a requirement, and I've never known the word to have that meaning.  So this usage is completely new to me.

Comment: As for this question:  "nothing actually prevented the robber from attempting to continue with the robbery did it?"  <- I would think the deterrent did.  After all, the robbery was going to occur, and yet it didn't.  So **something** must have prevented it.  Thanks again -- I look forward to your response after you get some rest.

Comment: As SomeGuy says, _actions_ are prevented, not people. The person being deterred **is** an outside force on the action, so there’s nothing wrong with counting it as a type of prevention. The act of deterring someone from doing X will often prevent X.

Answer (score 0):

The common use of the word 'deter' is in the field of nuclear deterrence or in the field in which I currently work - Security Guarding. We are 'visible deterrents'.

The headline in the [**Guardian**](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2016/jan/21/on-board-trident-submarine-hms-vigilant-pull-trigger-deterrence-failed) says it all, I feel :

> Onboard a Trident submarine: 'If I have to pull the trigger, deterrence has failed'

A deterrent is supposed to deter. And the proof of the effectiveness of the deterrent is that the subject was, indeed, deterred.

I would say, in answer to the OP, a resounding Yes !

If the action was not prevented then the deterrent failed.

It did not deter.

Comment: 'If the action was not prevented then the deterrent failed.' Unsound arguing. It may have delayed the fateful day; the 'hinder' rather than 'prevent' sense given in dictionaries is quite possible.

Answer (score -1):

Deterring can be achieved simply by the threat of action. My dictionary says, "To discourage or restrain from acting or proceeding." Sometimes peer pressure acts as a deterrent or the possibility of facing consequences.

Comment: I understand that deterring doesn't need to involve physical force, but that doesn't really answer my main question of whether or not it needs to be successful.

Example:  Bob wants to date my sister.  I don't want him to, so I scare him by telling him that if he does, I will punch him.  He gets scared, but not enough to completely dissuade him, so he dates my sister anyway.  
  
No action was prevented.  So, did I "deter" him or not?